# Download Canvas Image Png Chrome/Safari

Tags: javascript, canvas

Works in Firefox, and won't work in Safari, or Chrome.

```
 function loadimage()
    {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
       xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
       xmlhttp2=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
       xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
       xmlhttp2=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
       xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {

    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    rasterizeHTML.drawHTML(xmlhttp.responseText, canvas);
    var t=setTimeout(function(){copy()},3000)
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","/sm/<?=$sm[0];?>",true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}

function copy()
{
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var img    = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

document.getElementById('dl').href = img;
document.getElementById('dl').innerHTML = "Download";
}
```

Now I didn't write this, so I don't know too much JavaScript.  But the script works in Firefox. In Chrome, getting: Uncaught Security Error: An attempt was made to break through the security policy of the user-agent. For `toDataURL("image/png")`

Comment: Are you testing this by using your local files?

Comment: Are you open to using jQuery to simplify the AJAX code?

Comment: Evan, sorry not sure what you mean. Der, yes, sure

Comment: @DerFlatulator Yes sure

Comment: try hosting it from a server or use ip address instead of accessing it via localhost or file protocol

Comment: If the canvas is drawn from source (be it external or not), Chrome won't let you `toDateUrl` even if you're all doing in localhost. This is said to be a security restriction.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `<?=$sm[0];?>` is correctly preprocessed on the server, the following should do the same thing, but work cross-browser:

```
function loadImage() {
    $.get("sm/<?=$sm[0];?>", function (data) {
        rasterizeHTML.drawHTML(data, $('#canvas')[0]);
        setTimeout(copy, 3000);
    });
}

function copy() {
    var $canvas = $("#canvas");
    var img = $canvas[0].toDataURL("image/png");
    $('#dl').attr('href', img).text("Download");
}
```

Comment: Hmm weird, I changed to this, and the download was blank. I see you have "sm/ so I made the root url /sm/ and the variable is correct. It's an HTML file. But when correcting the path: http://www.domain.com/sm/<?=$sm[0];?> the Download isn't showing.

Comment: I made sure there wasnt anything wrong in the sm file, and just put some basic html, and still not working.   Just not too good with javascript.

Comment: I apologize. It does work. I just tested in Firefox, but doesn't Chrome. Still getting that error: please see screenshot here: http://screencast.com/t/6wahyfpuCa

Comment: Is the image stored on the same server?

Comment: Yes it is stored on the same server